# Photoshop CS6 clipping mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, clipping-mask

Sorry for being idiot but I try to recreate effect from tutorial and I might be paranoid but I think I can't get it right. This is how it looks in tutorial. I see it's supposed to be clipping mask (I think). Correct me if this icon means something different.

[image]

But what I get is this. Is this version difference or something? It really drives me crazy because I think my effect is different (I work on Photoshop CS6).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a **Gradient Map** while the tutorial is using simply **Gradient**. Gradient is somewhere higher in the Effects tab. Focus on the details.

[image]

Also, your layer named **Layer** appears to have a solid background while in the tutorial, he created a new layer and used a brush to paint WTF while everything else is transparent.

Try this, delete **Layer**, create a new layer, take your brush and paint something on the newly created layer.

Remove the gradient map and add Gradient instead, clip the B&W and Gradient to the new layer.